# Key/Main NSWindow Responder Chain for multiple NSPanel windows

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit

I have an NSDocument based app which also has a preferences NSPanel window. The preferences panel can then pop an NSFontPanel to configure a default font for my app. Challenge I have is that when the NSFontPanel is displayed, it becomes 'key' - which means the responder chain will direct changeFont: messages to the 'main' window (i.e. my document NOT my preferences panel)

Anyone know how this scenario should be handled? I guess, what I want is for the changeFont: message to goto the 'topmost non-key window' in this situation. I could do a quick check in my main window to check if preferences panel is visible and pass the message on - but that feels hacky...

Any suggestions would be most welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `NSNotiFication` by sending your `changeFont:` messages

Comment: Good idea - still need to code up something to decide who is best placed to handle the message - which is what the responder chain is for. Strikes me as a common architectural 'problem' so I'm hoping for something a little cleaner.